# HTML / CSS - Styling <b> or <i> tags instead of <span>

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I was just wondering if it's a good idea to do this.
For example if you want to create round-cornered tabs using CSS, you would need a structure like this:

```
<li> <a href="..."> <span> Tab </span> </a> </li>
...
```

then you put the left tab corner background on the link tag and the right one the span (maybe it's a bad example, because you could use the list tag to avoid the span, but you get my point :).

So, what if I used `<b>` instead of `<span>`, because it's shorter? Would it cause problems with certain browsers, or search engines?

Comment: and are there any other short tags I could use inside links?

Comment: Using <b> tags wouldn't cause any problems for browsers, but your markup won't be XHTML compliant. Also, the web development gods will smite you and forever disdain you.

Comment: I don't understand smiting and desdaining. Does that mean they will abuse me sexually?

Comment: Style the <li> and <a> tags. Add <span> or <div> if you need it. Don't use <b> or <i> for this.

Comment: You could use javascript to enhance the page. Users without javascript get a basic page, and if they have it enabled they get that extra good looking site ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tags have semantical meaning to the document. Indeed, a search engine interprets `<b>` in another way than `<span>`.

My five cents: Use the correct tags in first place, and optimize the size of the page source by using tags with shorter names in like 100'th place.

Answer (score 4):

`<span>` and `<b>` both have identical semantic meaning in HTML 4 (and XHTML 1): none. `<span>` because it's deliberately designed to have zero semantics, and `<b>` because it's purely presentational.

HTML5 slightly changes how `<i>` and `<b>` are described, essentially describing the sorts of purposes ‘italic’ and ‘bold’ text are typically put to. This is semantically weak but not quite semantics-free.

Either way, I wouldn't use `<b>` just to save a couple of characters. `<span>` is more explicit about what it is you're doing, adding an extra semantics-free element purely for styling purposes. (Until such time as you can get away with just using `border-radius`, in which case you won't need the wrapper.)

Answer (score 0):

`<b>` and `<i>` are no longer acceptible - as they describe formatting and not semantics. I do not believe they are in XHTML.